# Product wise shipping cost on same address

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, multishipping

I want to show different shipping price for different products acceding to their size and weight. I don't know how to implement this in Magento. It will create different order like multiple address system does at checkout. Please suggest me anyway to implement this feature.

[image: Currently, I am doing changes like this following image. But not able to divide each product's shipping cost. every time It showing its total cost.]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by csv, Just enable flat talble rates in backend

```
On the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configuration.
On the left panel, under Sales, select Shipping Methods.
Open the Table Rates section,

    Enable the shipping method by choosing Yes for that.
    Set the Title for the table rate shipping on the checkout page. You can use the default value - “Best Way” for the table rate title.
    Choose Conditions by the calculating methods: Weight v. Destination, Price v. Destination, or # of Items v. Destination.
    If the order includes virtal products for the price calculating, choose Yes in the ` Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation` field.
```

[image]

In csv you can sett differnet shipping costs.

Comment: Is this system will show different product shipping cost separately like I am showing in my image?

Comment: yes, the same you want